# Setting PHP variables in this foreach loop

Tags: php, sql, foreach

i have a database table that is set up like so::

```
ID | NAME  | VALUE
1  | item1 | item1value
1  | item2 | item2value
```

and so on...

what i want to do, is on a sql query, loop through all the rows and set a variable which is:

```
$name = $value
```

This should then set e.g. 2 variables of:

```
$item1 = item1value
$item2 = item2value
```

How can i do this in a foreach loop?

```
CONNECTION DETAILS ETC

$dsn        = "mysql:host=$server;dbname=$database";

$db = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
$db->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

$query = "SELECT * FROM `values`";

try
{ 
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
    $stmt->execute(); 
} 
catch(PDOException $ex) 
{ 
    die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
} 

$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(); 

foreach($rows as $row){

   // WHAT TO PUT HERE? 

}
```

Comment: I think an associative array would work best for you here.

Comment: You do **NOT** want to generate a variable-per-value. That's just insane. Use an array.

Answer (score 2):

You could do

```
foreach($rows as $row){
   $$row['name'] = $row['value']
}
```

Or you could use an associative array which is a **BETTER WAY TO DO IT** and do

```
$aResults = array();
foreach($rows as $row){
   $aResults[$row['name']] = $row['value']
}
```

This first way is **bad practice** because the variable names will change depending on the values in the database.  Someone might change something in the database which could break your code

Comment: man are you kidding?! that's a bad practice, just tell him to use an array!

Comment: @CodeBird Yeah I did, see the bold

Comment: the first example works fine, but i want to learn he proper way of doing things. What should i be doing with the array after?

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($rows as $row){
   list( $var, $value) = each( $row);
   $$var = $value;
}
```

As others have stated, this is incredibly bad practice and I have only provided this response under duress and to directly answer the question!!

It is bad because it has the potential to overwrite existing variables and you have no guarantee that some numpty has not damaged your database table of name => value associations in some way.

Comment: This will do what the OP wanted. But I don't know if it's a good idea ;)

Comment: that's a bad practice!

Comment: I would rather put unvalidated `$_GET` parameters into my `eval()` and `exec()` instead of using this code ...

Comment: I simply answered the question but since everyone is jumping on the bad aspects of this, I've expanded the answer :-)